# Access to "parent" or "owner" function C++

Tags: c++, relationship, class-design, ownership-semantics

I have a class, `Game`, which has in argument a `std::vector` of another class, `Case`. In this class `Case`, I have a function which tells me when we click on it. And I want to send a signal to my object `Game`, which owns the `Cases`, when a `Case` is pressed.
In game.h :

```
class Game
{
public:
    Game();
    void doSomething();

private:
    std::vector<Case> board;
};
```

And in case.h :

```
class Case
{
    public:
        Case(Game &g);
        void functionWhichIsCalledWhenCaseIsPressed();
    private:
        Game game;
};
```

So, when the `functionWhichIsCalledWhenCaseIsPressed()` is called, I want to call the function `doSomething()`.
EDIT :

I tried, but I also need to create a case out of the vector... Actually, I have a `Case c;` in my Game.h... And I cannot initialize it... I tried `c = Game(*this);` But I have an error :

```
error: object of type 'Case' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly delete
```

EDIT : Thank you, it's done !

Comment: One way to do this would be to have each Case store a pointer back to the Game object. Would that resolve your issue?

Comment: I would go the other way - have `Case` hold a function pointer or `std::function` that it can call when needed, and then have `Game` assign `doSomething()` to that when it populates the `std::vector`.

Comment: check out [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Answer (score 2):

For this to happen, you need to enable a navigation from a `Case` to its owning `Game`.  One way to do this is to keep in each Case a reference or a pointer to the owner,  and initalize this reference at construction:

```
class Game; 
class Case
{
    public:
        Case(Game& x);
        void functionWhichIsCalledWhenCaseIsPressed();
    private: 
        Game &game;  // <<<<-------------- reference to owner
};
```

With these prerequisite, you can easily invoke the parent's function:

```
Case::Case(Game& x) : game(x){
}
void Case::functionWhichIsCalledWhenCaseIsPressed() {
    cout<<"Clicked"<<endl; 
    game.doSomething();    //<<<===== invoke the function of the owner
}
```

This requires that the game initializes the board and provides the right parameters to the constructor:

```
Game::Game() {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        board.push_back(Case(*this));
}
void Game::doSomething() { cout<<"click on game"<<endl; }
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/4DibPa)